# how to display database data using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'],  
        datasets: [
            {
         fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
         strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
         pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
         pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
         pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
         data: [30, 50, 75, 59]
     },
        ]
    };

    var context = document.querySelector('#graph').getContext('2d');

    new Chart(context).Line(data);
</script>
```

```html
<canvas id="graph" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

```html
public function tracker()
  {
    $statistics = DiraStatistics::all();
    return view('AltHr.Chatbot.tracker', compact('statistics'));
  }
```

Hi guys so im new to javascript i would like to know how can i view the data replacing "labels(jan,feb,march)" and "data(30,50,75)".

im doing this in laravel but so in my controller ive called the database values as:

i need the labels from column : date_access
and data from column : question_asked

I would appreciate your help thanks

### id  |   date_access   |   question_asked

### 1   |  2017-09-25      |           9

2   |  2017-09-26      |           5

..

Answer (score 0):

Using the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) your code can look something like this:

```
fetch("someurl")//assuming get request, you need post then you need to pass a config object
.then(response => response.json())
.then(
  json => ({
    labels: json.months,//this depends on your json data

    datasets: [
      {
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: json.data//this depends on your json data
      }
    ]
  })
)
.then(
  data => {
    var context = document.querySelector('#graph').getContext('2d');    
    new Chart(context).Line(data);        
  }
)
```

If you want to support older browsers you need a [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch)

Examples of fetch api can be found [here](https://github.com/mdn/fetch-examples).

Your data can come from [laravel restfull resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

Can you Try this one buddy.

Controller

```
    public function tracker()
      {
        $statistics = DiraStatistics::all();
        labels = [];
        data =[];
        foreach ($statistics as $key => $statistic) {
            labels=  $statistic->date_access;
            data =  $statistic->question_asked;
        }
         return view('AltHr.Chatbot.tracker', compact('labels','data'));
      }
```

js in blade.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      var data = {
      labels: ['{{ $labels[0] }}', '{{ $labels[1] }}', '{{ $labels[2] }}', '{{ $labels[3] }}'],

      datasets: [
        {
          fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
          strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
          pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
          pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          data: ['{{ $data[0] }}', '{{ $data[0] }}', '{{ $data[0] }}', '{{ $data[0] }}']
        },
      ]
    };

    var context = document.querySelector('#graph').getContext('2d');

    new Chart(context).Line(data);

</script>
```